# How to remove unknown commands from shell terminal history (zsh)

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to setup my history in zsh. I have activated option like **HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS** which removes duplicated commands in the history.

But I am also looking for some option that can remove commands that don't exist which return 127 "command not found".

Comment: `(zsh or bash)` Please pick one, they differ. You tagged `zsh`, so choose `zsh`. If you are interested in `bash`, ask a separate question for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such option in Zsh, but this can be easily achieved with the [`zsh-hist` plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-hist/):

```
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook

command-not-found () {
  # -f: force
  # -s: silent
  # -1: most recent history item
  (( ? == 127 )) && 
      hist -fs delete -1
}

add-zsh-hook precmd command-not-found
```

This will automatically delete the last command line from history, if it returned `127`.

Alternatively, in addition to deleting it, you can also load the deleted command into the editing buffer, so you can immediately fix whatever typo you made, by using `hist fix` instead of `hist delete`:

```
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook

command-not-found () {
  (( ? == 127 )) && 
      hist -fs fix -1
}

add-zsh-hook precmd command-not-found
```